# Discord.py how do I make a mute command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As the title says. I'm trying to figure out how to make a mute command using discord.py rewrite. I'm thinking that we need to have a "mute" role where the command used gives the user the "mute" role and for how long. How do I achieve this.

I already have

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mute_members)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member):
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to have a database setup in which you can add and remove users. Then you can use the `on_message` event and check if the author is in the database, if it is then delete the message. You could also just use a list/file for it to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Muted role and make your bot add the role to the user you want to mute:

```py
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send("role added")
```