# Adding role to a specific person on discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I've been making a moderator bot on python.
The bot should give the person a muted role when he has got a blacklisted word in his message.

```
badwords = ["лузер", "расизм", "нацизм"] # words examples
for word in badwords:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            if str(message.author) != "ResadeskerBOT#7104":
                mutedRole = # I do not know what to put here
                await member.add_roles(mutedRole)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mutedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Muted')
```

See also: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974280/discord-py-how-do-i-make-a-mute-command)